# PhpStorm fails to connect to FTP but FileZilla connects OK

Tags: ftp, phpstorm

I am using an FTP connection in PhpStorm for transferring files. With **FileZilla** I am able to connect easily but unable to connect via **PhpStorm**. I have set up a custom port for ftp. Below are the settings.

[image]

**Log File**

```
2022-08-25 16:47:57,755 [1925474]  DEBUG - t.config.sockets.SocketWrapper - Default socket connection to /115.50.20.78:63425 10000 
2022-08-25 16:47:59,882 [1927601]   WARN - t.connections.RemoteConnection - Retrying 
connecting to ftp://115.50.20.78:1125/ in @2fdca0a0: 1 iterations 
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not list the contents of folder 
"ftp://116.58.28.78:1469/".
at 
org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChildren(AbstractFileObject.java:1111)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.getChildren(FtpFileObject.java:436)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChild(AbstractFileObject.java:1033)
at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionPool.lambda$createConnection$0(RemoteConnectionPool.java:265)
at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:20)
at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:11)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.call(ApplicationImpl.java:265)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.config.sockets.SocketWrapper.connect(SocketWrapper.java:50)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:920)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:760)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FTPExtendedClient.initiateMListParsing(FTPExtendedClient.java:47)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FTPExtendedClient.mlistDir(FTPExtendedClient.java:29)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpJBHelper.listFiles(FtpJBHelper.java:66)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FTPClientWrapper.listFilesInDirectory(FTPClientWrapper.java:169)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FTPClientWrapper.listFiles(FTPClientWrapper.java:151)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.doGetChildren(FtpFileObject.java:128)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.doListChildren(FtpFileObject.java:452)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChildren(AbstractFileObject.java:1102)
... 14 more
2022-08-25 16:48:07,958 [1935677]   WARN - t.connections.RemoteConnection - Connection cancelled to ftp://115.50.20.78:1125/ in @2fdca0a0 
2022-08-25 16:48:07,958 [1935677]   INFO - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - java.net.SocketException: Socket closed 
2022-08-25 16:48:11,708 [1939427]   INFO - j.ide.actions.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1
```

**PhpStorm Version**

```
PhpStorm 2021.1.1
Build #PS-211.7036.8, built on April 15, 2021
Licensed to PhpStorm Evaluator
Expiration date: September 21, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.10+9-b1341.35 amd64
VM: Dynamic Code Evolution 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1498M
Cores: 4
Registry: run.processes.with.pty=TRUE
Non-Bundled Plugins: io.zhile.research.ide-eval-resetter (2.3.5)
```

**Update 1**

So I have checked the server side and found the below logs on the FileZilla server

**With Passive Mode**

```
(000056)8/25/2022 22:50:23 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> Connected, sending welcome message...
(000056)8/25/2022 22:50:23 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta
(000056)8/25/2022 22:50:23 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
(000056)8/25/2022 22:50:23 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> 220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
(000056)8/25/2022 22:50:23 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> USER app
(000056)8/25/2022 22:50:23 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> 331 Password required for app
(000056)8/25/2022 22:50:23 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> PASS *********
(000056)8/25/2022 22:50:23 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> 230 Logged on
(000056)8/25/2022 22:50:23 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> TYPE I
(000056)8/25/2022 22:50:23 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> 200 Type set to I
(000056)8/25/2022 22:50:24 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> SYST
(000056)8/25/2022 22:50:24 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
(000056)8/25/2022 22:50:24 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> PASV
(000056)8/25/2022 22:50:24 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,20,1,237,90)
(000056)8/25/2022 22:50:27 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> QUIT
(000056)8/25/2022 22:50:27 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> 221 Goodbye
(000056)8/25/2022 22:50:27 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> disconnected.
(000057)8/25/2022 22:50:28 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> Connected, sending welcome message...
(000057)8/25/2022 22:50:28 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta
(000057)8/25/2022 22:50:28 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
(000057)8/25/2022 22:50:28 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> 220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
(000057)8/25/2022 22:50:28 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> USER app
(000057)8/25/2022 22:50:28 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> 331 Password required for app
(000057)8/25/2022 22:50:28 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> PASS *********
(000057)8/25/2022 22:50:28 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> 230 Logged on
(000057)8/25/2022 22:50:28 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> TYPE I
(000057)8/25/2022 22:50:28 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> 200 Type set to I
(000057)8/25/2022 22:50:28 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> SYST
(000057)8/25/2022 22:50:28 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
(000057)8/25/2022 22:50:28 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> PASV
(000057)8/25/2022 22:50:28 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,20,1,237,91)
(000057)8/25/2022 22:50:40 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> PASV
(000057)8/25/2022 22:50:40 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,20,1,237,92)
(000057)8/25/2022 22:50:50 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> QUIT
(000057)8/25/2022 22:50:50 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> 221 Goodbye
(000057)8/25/2022 22:50:50 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> disconnected.
```

**Without Passive Mode**

```
(000062)8/25/2022 22:56:38 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> Connected, sending welcome message...
(000062)8/25/2022 22:56:38 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta
(000062)8/25/2022 22:56:38 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
(000062)8/25/2022 22:56:38 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> 220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
(000062)8/25/2022 22:56:39 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> USER app
(000062)8/25/2022 22:56:39 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> 331 Password required for app
(000062)8/25/2022 22:56:39 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.80.220)> PASS *********
(000062)8/25/2022 22:56:39 PM - app (192.168.80.220> 230 Logged on
(000062)8/25/2022 22:56:39 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> TYPE I
(000062)8/25/2022 22:56:39 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> 200 Type set to I
(000062)8/25/2022 22:56:39 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> SYST
(000062)8/25/2022 22:56:39 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
(000062)8/25/2022 22:56:39 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> PORT 192,168,43,189,230,71
(000062)8/25/2022 22:56:39 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> 200 Port command successful
(000062)8/25/2022 22:56:40 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> LIST
(000062)8/25/2022 22:56:40 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> 150 Opening data channel for directory list.
(000062)8/25/2022 22:56:50 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> QUIT
(000062)8/25/2022 22:56:50 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> 425 Can't open data connection.
(000062)8/25/2022 22:56:50 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> 221 Goodbye
(000062)8/25/2022 22:56:50 PM - app (192.168.80.220)> disconnected.
```

Already tried with **Passive Mode** and **Always use LIST command** but still no luck.

Comment: i guess it's a sftp server

Comment: No, it's not because with the same settings it working on FileZilla

Comment: Perhaps it's the mappings that are wrong, `Could not list the contents of folder 
"ftp://x.x.x.x:yyyy/".` is a strange error, it does not looks like a folder to me, and it does not even correspond to the ip you are connecting to

Comment: _"No, it's not..."_ - I would recommend using FTPS or SFTP instead though. FTP is not particularly secure since all data, including the credentials, are sent in plain text.

Comment: @M.Eriksson then what changes you will recommend me at server and client level for `FTPS` or `SFTP`?

Comment: I have added the server log as well kindly check

Comment: You might want to enable the extended deployment logging, that should help to better understand the issue origins. To do that, just add the following line to the "Help > Diagnostic tools > Debug Log Settings":
#com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment

Also, if you are about to use FTPS check if you use TLS newer than 1.2:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-60318

Comment: @duck_in_hat should I remove `#` ?